# How to call a function of a class from a pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to call a public function of a class ( `char* get_name(void)` )
with a pointer ,who points this class!

```
classPtr = &Class ;
cout << ClassPtr->get_name(void) ;
```

But i am getting error by compiler !
Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Better post an MCVE.

Comment: And what type is `classPtr`?

Comment: If you want to call a function that does not take any parameters, use `get_name()`, not `get_name(void)`.

Comment: no match for operator <<

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mean:

```
classPtr = &Class ;
cout << classPtr->get_name(void) ;
```

Also, I'm not too sure what &Class means, I assume Class is an object and not the class name ;)